# What path on disk does a containerd snapshot key map to?

Tags: kubernetes, snapshot, containerd

I want to remove a snapshot from a node in our Kubernates cluster:

```
/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/NNNN
```

But I am unable to map this path to any snapshots as reported by `ctr -n k8s.io snapshots list`. I have tried the `usage` command, but the INODE does not seem to map to the NNNN entry in the `snapshots` directory, because the "usage" list is not a subset of the entries in the directory.

Is there a way to understand if snapshot/NNNN is in use?

Answer (score 2):

The mapping is stored in `/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/metadata.db`

This database file map between the SHA256 hash of the snapshot and the snapshot id (the 'nnnn' number used as a directory name). the database format is Bolt DB (the library used for read/write is [bbolt](https://github.com/etcd-io/bbolt)).

I have written an open source project that, among other things, [reads that database](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/containercp).